# How do I access the contents of an mSecure backup?

Tags: backup, restore, password-management

I had an iPhone with mSecure as my password manager, and have some backups.

Now I no longer have the iPhone, and it is not clear to me how to restore from Windows mSecure what data is in the backup. I tried to log in using the email address used for the backups, and the password I used, but that was a no-go, and a glance at https://support.msecure.com/en/support/solutions/articles/36000064484 seems to state that I will need a fresh account to use mSecure.

How can I access the passwords stored in an mSecure backup for which I have the (old-school) password? I have at present Windows and Linux available.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem using android - dating back to software bought in 2012.
This is the response I had from mSeven Software.
I have not resolved my issue yet, but this may help guide your enquiry:

> You can restore the backup into mSecure on your Android or on your computer. You will need mSecure 3.5.7 on your computer to restore the backup on that device. You can find mSecure 3 here: [Install mSecure 3.5.7 for Windows](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/msecure-password-manager-and-digital-wallet/9nblggh62pc8?rtc=2.01&activetab=pivot:overviewtab)
>   ​
>
> Once you install mSecure 3, you will need to set the password the same as you were using for mSecure when you backup was made, then you can restore your backup by clicking on File > Restore in the Menu Bar at the top of the app window.
>   ​
>
> It's not possible to get the data out of the backup without the password used to encrypt the file, so if you don't know that password, there isn't anything we can do to help retrieve the information.

Comment: How did you get this response?  Email?  Web page?  If at all possible, link to a publicly readable copy of the message.  And that “You can find mSecure 3 here: Install mSecure 3.5.7 for Windows” looks like it’s meant to be a link; can you tell us what that’s supposed to point to? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: Thank you for volunteering a response! I've tried to touch up your response with a download link and improved paragraph formatting; we'll see if my revision passes review. Welcome to SO, and I hope you continue to contribute!